# How default.target (systemd) is evoked from kernel

Tags: linux, service, filesystems, kernel, systemd

I know systemd starts from default.service file that is there in "/etc/systemd/system". From there  all services get started. But  actually i want to know how defalt.target is evoked  while kernel is loading. which file executes default.target. How would kernel know weather i am using sys V init or systemd?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel is not involved at all. It just executes /sbin/init which in this case decides what target to execute.

The kernel does not know or care what init system you are using.